# How to full width to inlined buttons?

Tags: html, css

I'm having this kind of problem because I already tried this code:

```css
.form {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  background: #CCC;
}

.btn-one,
.btn-two {
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  background: Steelblue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <button class="btn-one">Button 1</button>
  <button class="btn-two">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

But the result is that the **.btn-two** ends up being on the new line or at the bottom of **.btn-one**. 
How can I make this full width without spaces while they're inlined? I hope someone will suggest an answer without the use of Bootstrap. Only in pure CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `float: right;` to `.btn-two`:

```
.btn-two {
  float: right;
}
```

See working example below:

```css
.form {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  background: #CCC;
}

.btn-one, .btn-two {
  position: relative;
  height: 35px;
  width: 50%;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  background: Steelblue;
  /* display: inline-block; <-- No need for display */
}

.btn-two {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <button class="btn-one">Button 1</button>
  <button class="btn-two">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I thought using float will make the element absolute or the parent element which is the **form** will not make a space for the element.

Comment: @DominoWallace I don't agree a lot with this *float* solution as it sounds like a hack, all what you need is to use the code as its and remove the white space between the inline-block elemen (check the duplicate)

Comment: Yes, for a more solid and complete solution please see the duplicate marked by @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 4):

```
.form {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    background: #CCC;
    display: flex;
}
.btn-one, .btn-two {
    position: relative;
    height: 35px; width: 50%;
    border: 0; border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
    background: Steelblue;
    display: inline-block;
}
<div class="form">
    <button class="btn-one">Button 1</button>
    <button class="btn-two">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Use `display: flex;`

HTML:

```
<div class="form">
    <button class="btn-one">Button 1</button>
    <button class="btn-two">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.form {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    background: #CCC;
    display: flex;
}
.btn-one, .btn-two {
    position: relative;
    height: 35px; width: 50%;
    border: 0; border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
    background: Steelblue;
}
```

Try This

```css
.form {
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    background: #CCC;
    display: flex;
}
.btn-one, .btn-two {
    position: relative;
    height: 35px; width: 50%;
    border: 0; border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
    background: Steelblue;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
    <button class="btn-one">Button 1</button>
    <button class="btn-two">Button 2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: on basis of which strategy you are putting the 2nd property on the same line?

Comment: I don't like Flex for its compatibility issues.